# In Binomial distribution, the number of trials follows the Binomial distribution

Tags: probability-distributions, binomial-distribution

We consider the following two random variables:
$X \sim Binomial(1+N,\alpha)$ and $N \sim Binomial (W,\delta)$

Then does the following hold? 
$P(X=x,N=y)=$${1+y}\choose{x}$ $\alpha^x(1-\alpha)^{1+y-x}$

Comment: How do you define $\operatorname{binom}(0,p)$?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Thanks for the comment. I have updated the question.